# Web Tokens and HttpSessionState ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, caching, json-web-token

Good day, 
Is the following a good solution or is there alternative or is this bad.

I have a ASP MVC client application and it talks to a HTTP API (also Microsoft but does not matter).
In my client application I'm storing session data (HttpSessionState) for data the user is busy with (cache). Obviously the session data is stored against a session ID which is the instance (session id per client browser). My first problem to overcome is I need to store data using a Unique key for the user (application user) so that I dont override or remove cache if theres more than one logon in the browser. I might have internet explorer open with multiple sessions to the application. This might be the same user two instances or two sessions different session.

When I authenticate the user I have a ID/webtoken. Could one use this as the identifier and store cache with that key included, So if the user logout the cache is clear only for that "logon". Remember this is HttpSessionState which is stored on the server not client browser.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to login to two different user accounts in one session as you have only one Authentication cookie shared between all your open tabs. If you open another session, no matter if the user is the same or different you will have a different session id so you will refer to a different session data.

Also remember to secure your WebAPI using tokens as cookie authentication is not recommended and valuable for XSS attacks.

Comment: I'm not using cookie or Authentication cookie? When I talk about session I purely talk about ASP HttpSessionState, which is per browser client.

Comment: 1 browser open = 1 session cookie = 1 session id = 1 HttpSessionState collection that this Id is referring to. You said: ".....if theres more than one logon in the browser" - how do you want to log-in more than one user to you application at the same time in a one browser session?

Comment: Multiple tabs open in browser, so example chrome open with two or more tabs.

Comment: Well, give it a try. When you're logging out, the Authentication cookie is deleted and this cookie is shared between all your websites  (tabs) within one session. That means when you go back to the previous tab and refresh the page, your user will be log-out. If you change a user in one tab, the old user will become a new user in every other tab after refreshing the page.